# No puedo capturar el output de un procedure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Al debugear una funcion que me permite crear un registro, no logro obtener el output del procedure.'Output' nunca cambia su valor con que se inicializa ("").

```
        string Agregar(Empleado reg)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            string output = "";
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);
            try
            {
                cn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pregunta02_3 @codEmp,@nom,@ape,@idpais,@email", cn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", reg.nomEmployee);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ape", reg.apeEmployee);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpais", reg.idpais);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", reg.emailEmployee);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@codEmp", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          
                output = cmd.Parameters["@codEmp"].Value.ToString();
                mensaje = $"El codigo {output} ya existe";
                if (!output.Equals("0"))
                    mensaje = $"Se ha registro el Empleado de codigo {output}";
            }
            catch (SqlException ex) { mensaje = ex.Message; }
            finally { cn.Close(); }

            return mensaje;
        }
```

El procedure me devuelve un codEmpleado aleatorio gracias a una funcion que genera numeros aleatorios que no esten en la tabla, si ya existe regresa 0.

```
CREATE VIEW vw_random
AS
SELECT RAND() AS Value


CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION fn_pregunta02()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ran_value INT;
    SET @ran_value = CAST(floor((SELECT Value FROM vw_random)*11) AS int);
    IF @ran_value IN (SELECT idEmployee FROM tb_employee)
    BEGIN
        SET @ran_value = 0;
    END
    RETURN @ran_value
END;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE  sp_pregunta02_3
@codEmp int output,
@nom varchar(255),
@ape varchar(255),
@idpais char(3),
@email varchar(255)
as
BEGIN 
    SET @codEmp = dbo.fn_pregunta02();
    PRINT @codEmp
    IF @codEmp <> 0
    BEGIN 
        insert into tb_employee 
        values(@codEmp, @nom, @ape, @idpais, @email)
    END
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE  sp_pregunta02_3
@codEmp int output,
@nom varchar(255),
@ape varchar(255),
@idpais char(3),
@email varchar(255)
as
BEGIN 
    SET @codEmp = dbo.fn_pregunta02();
    PRINT @codEmp -- Esto es a nivel de SQL Server "Consola"
    IF @codEmp <> 0
    BEGIN 
        insert into tb_employee 
        values(@codEmp, @nom, @ape, @idpais, @email)
    END
    SELECT @codEmp -- Esto te va a retornar el valor que buscas.
END
```

Ejemplo basado en:

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/

Comment: Entiendo que lo que busca en la pregunta es obtener el parametro, no mostrarlo en un select.

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutar el código?

Comment: No funciona, output sigue siendo un string vacio

Comment: @Frnk Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que tienes en `dbo.fn_pregunta02();`

Comment: pregunta editada

Comment: ¿Qué tan seguro estás que siempre va a regresar un valor diferente al vacío esa función?